# asp.net mvc get jQuery to work in a view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get jQuery working in my view but I cannot get a simple alert box to appear!

My _Layout page has the default bundles defined before the closing 'body' tag:

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
 @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

At the top of my View have a script section:

```
@section scripts {
<script type=”text/javascript”>
          $(function() {
      alert("hello");
    });
</script>
}
```

The source code from the rendered page shows this before the closing 'body' tag:

```
   <script src="/bundles/jquery?v=Aj1GKhwLcrKGfvkl6W3KyVVaqQJQ2zhPCS3xQ5-_xuE1"></script>

   <script src="/bundles/bootstrap?v=2Fz3B0iizV2NnnamQFrx-NbYJNTFeBJ2GM05SilbtQU1">   </script>


<script type=”text/javascript”>
          $(function() {
      alert("hello");
    });
</script>
```

Why am I not seeing an alert message??

Comment: what error are your getting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the *smart double quotes or should i say curly quotes* from here `<script type=”text/javascript”>`:

```
@section scripts {
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
           alert("hello");
      });
   </script>
}
```

---

`”` is different against `"` double quotes.

Comment: Jeebus! That was it *facepalm*